# Java kill 3 thread dump output redirect

Tags: java, terminal, thread-dump

Is it possible to redirect `kill 3 <java_pid>` thread dump output?

I have huge system_out.log files on servers with many lines (>500mb), it's very hard to parse and look for dump.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of trying to figure out how to redirect just use a tool that does what you want. Any of these:

- [jstack](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/unix/jstack.html)
- [jcmd](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/troubleshoot/tooldescr006.html) (using `Thread.print`)
- [astack](https://github.com/HubSpot/astack)

Comment: I know about jstack (installs with jvm by default). But this tools not available on servers that I manage, so this question about kill -3 dump. Anyway thanks (I don't know about astack)

Comment: If you need debugging tools on your servers, you can and should install them. `:)`

Answer (score 2):

Please append following JVM arguments to your application. Thread dump should be captured at dump.log.

> -XX:+UnlockDiagnosticVMOptions -XX:+LogVMOutput -XX:LogFile=dump.log

Please note it does not redirect, but enables JVM diagnostic logging. So, there could be possible over head as well.

As suggested by Matt, you can use jstack (etc) to capture thread dump in a file. For that you can simply copy the JDK directory in your server. But, if you want to package & ship JDK with your application (for debugging later) please check if there is any licensing implication or not.